# Dropdown menu does not trigger in oneui 3.0.2 (in Firefox)

Tags: firefox, xpages, xpages-extlib

I use an dropDownButton from the extlib, which does not work when I changed to OneUI 3.0.2 (from 2.1, in which it works fine).

Happens in firefox (31.8), not in (a very old) IE. Firebug shows the following error in its console, when I click on on of the dropdown entries:

TypeError: _9.getAttribute is not a function ,

and it point to ...{return _6[_9.getAttribute("widgetId")];}... in the lib -extlib.dijit.OneUIv302Dialog&-extlib.dijit.OneUIv302Menu&@Eya.js

Is it a (known) bug?

my code:

```
                                                <xe:dropDownButton
                                                    id="dropDownButton1">
                                                    <xe:this.treeNodes>
                                                        <xe:basicContainerNode
                                                            label="IAM">
                                                            <xe:this.children>
                                                                <xe:basicLeafNode
                                                                    submitValue="approve1" label="approve selected">
                                                                </xe:basicLeafNode>
                                                                <xe:basicLeafNode
                                                                    submitValue="reject0" label="reject selected">
                                                                </xe:basicLeafNode>
                                                            </xe:this.children>
                                                        </xe:basicContainerNode>
                                                    </xe:this.treeNodes>
                                                    <xp:eventHandler
                                                        event="onItemClick" submit="true"
                                                        refreshMode="complete">
                                                        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:submitIAMAction()}]]></xe:this.action>
                                                    </xp:eventHandler>
                                                </xe:dropDownButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the Extension Library DropDownButton in conjunction with `OneUI V3.0.2` without any troubles.

[image]

*UPDATE* "Output on server console":

[image]

---

I am working with the following environment:

- Firefox **42**
- Domino Server **9.0.1FP4**
- Extension Library Version **9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301**

It could be a problem with your Domino Server and/or Extension Library Version?

Try to do some updates on your environment.

Comment: Georg, did you put some ssjs code into the event? Like my submitIAMAction()? 

My dropdown shows correctly, but the ssjs function is not triggered. 

extlib is 901v00_14.20150831-1301

Server is 9.0.1 FP3HF236

I cannot update Firefox, "company version"

Comment: Yes, I have a `print("test") ` statement in the event and that works perfect

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the same issue we had. In our case, I think the drop down entries could still work if you clicked on the actual text in the drop down option, clicking in the 'white space' would not work.

We found a solution thanks to **Serdar Basegmez** in the Defect list in ExtLib project on OpenNTF
http://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/defects/0FFE08B1FC57FE6A86257D91004C156D

Give this a try:
put the following in a javascript library.

```
if(dojo.isMozilla) dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dijit.registry.backupByNode=dijit.registry.byNode;
    dijit.registry.byNode=function(node) {
        if(node.getAttribute) {
            return dijit.registry.backupByNode(node);
        } else {
            return dijit.registry.backupByNode(node.parentNode);
        }
    }
});
```

and then add your theme: (add add as a resource to a single page)

```
<resources>
    <script src="/fixDropDownButton.js" clientSide="true"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</resources>
```